# Passing information to Stripe checkout (or elements)

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.js

I have a checkout form which has already asked a customer for the name, email address, shipping, billing and post code information - and have saved that to my order model. I may also obviously have a situation where a customer has created an account - so have that information too when they login.

With Stripe (checkout) I want to pass that information when creating the form. I know I can pass the email address of the customer, but is it possible to pass the other parameters I've mentioned? At the moment, it appears that the customer would be forced to enter the same information again (which would be particularly annoying if we wanted to pass the shipping and billing address). Even the zip code doesn't get populated, even though I am passing this to the form.

I haven't tried using Elements yet, and in that case, I would really want to pass the customer's name, email address and zip code at the very least.

Is this possible - or I have to collect all the information from Stripe and then use the response back to populate these parameters in the order model on the server side?

Many thanks in advance.